# Group array php and count

Tags: php

```
$data = [
     [
       id: '1',
       date_created: '2021-11-14T23:22:53.558225+00:00',
     ],
     [
       id: '2',
       date_created: '2021-11-14T23:22:00.558225+00:00',
     ],
     [
       id: '3',
       date_created: '2021-11-15T11:22:53.558225+00:00',
     ],
]
```

Help to get a new array, you need to group by date and count the number of resulting arrays starting from the first day.Here is an example of a new array

```
$new_array = [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,2,1]
```

Comment: what you have tried for that? Please share your code.

Comment: unfortunately, I don't even have any thoughts, I tried using group_by

Comment: Can you explain what you want from the data?

Comment: I need to get an array like in the example $new_array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose it can be done with a loop

```
<?php 
$data = [
     [
       'id' => '1',
       'date_created' => '2021-11-14T23:22:53.558225+00:00',
     ],
     [
       'id' => '2',
       'date_created' => '2021-11-14T23:22:00.558225+00:00',
     ],
     [
       'id' => '3',
       'date_created' => '2021-11-15T11:22:53.558225+00:00',
     ],
];

$res = array();
foreach($data as $row) {
    if(!isset($res[gmdate('d', strtotime($row['date_created']))]))
        $res[gmdate('d', strtotime($row['date_created']))] = 0;
    // array index, (current date of month) gmdate('d', strtotime($row['date_created'])) 
    $res[gmdate('d', strtotime($row['date_created']))]++;
}
print_r($res);
```